# How to simplify an inductive predicate by evaluation?

Tags: isabelle

I defined a very simple object-oriented model. The model defines a set of classes and a set of associations.

```
nonterminal fmaplets and fmaplet

syntax
  "_fmaplet"  :: "['a, 'a] ⇒ fmaplet"              ("_ /↦⇩f/ _")
  "_fmaplets" :: "['a, 'a] ⇒ fmaplet"              ("_ /[↦⇩f]/ _")
  ""          :: "fmaplet ⇒ fmaplets"              ("_")
  "_FMaplets" :: "[fmaplet, fmaplets] ⇒ fmaplets"  ("_,/ _")
  "_FMapUpd"  :: "['a ⇀ 'b, fmaplets] ⇒ 'a ⇀ 'b" ("_/'(_')" [900, 0] 900)
  "_FMap"     :: "fmaplets ⇒ 'a ⇀ 'b"             ("(1[_])")

syntax (ASCII)
  "_fmaplet"  :: "['a, 'a] ⇒ fmaplet"              ("_ /|->f/ _")
  "_fmaplets" :: "['a, 'a] ⇒ fmaplet"              ("_ /[|->f]/ _")

translations
  "_FMapUpd m (_FMaplets xy ms)"      ⇌ "_FMapUpd (_FMapUpd m xy) ms"
  "_FMapUpd m (_fmaplet  x y)"        ⇌ "CONST fmupd x y m"
  "_FMap ms"                          ⇌ "_FMapUpd (CONST fmempty) ms"
  "_FMap (_FMaplets ms1 ms2)"         ↽ "_FMapUpd (_FMap ms1) ms2"
  "_FMaplets ms1 (_FMaplets ms2 ms3)" ↽ "_FMaplets (_FMaplets ms1 ms2) ms3"

datatype classes1 =
  Object | Person | Employee | Customer | Project | Task | Sprint

abbreviation "associations ≡ [
  STR ''ProjectManager'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''projects'' ↦⇩f (Project, 0::nat, 100::nat),
    STR ''manager'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 1, 1)],
  STR ''ProjectMember'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''member_of'' ↦⇩f (Project, 0, 100),
    STR ''members'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 1, 20)],
  STR ''ManagerEmployee'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''line_manager'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 0, 1),
    STR ''project_manager'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 0, 100),
    STR ''employees'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 3, 7)],
  STR ''ProjectCustomer'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''projects'' ↦⇩f (Project, 0, 100),
    STR ''customer'' ↦⇩f (Customer, 1, 1)],
  STR ''ProjectTask'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''project'' ↦⇩f (Project, 1, 1),
    STR ''tasks'' ↦⇩f (Task, 0, 100)],
  STR ''SprintTaskAssignee'' ↦⇩f [
    STR ''sprint'' ↦⇩f (Sprint, 0, 10),
    STR ''tasks'' ↦⇩f (Task, 0, 5),
    STR ''assignee'' ↦⇩f (Employee, 0, 1)]]"
```

I defined also a `class_roles` predicate which relates a class to a set of association ends navigable from this class:

```
lemma fmember_code_predI [code_pred_intro]:
  "x |∈| xs" if "Predicate_Compile.contains (fset xs) x"
  using that by (simp add: Predicate_Compile.contains_def fmember.rep_eq)

code_pred fmember
  by (simp add: Predicate_Compile.contains_def fmember.rep_eq)

definition "assoc_end_class ≡ fst"

inductive assoc_refer_class where
  "role |∈| fmdom ends ⟹
   fmlookup ends role = Some end ⟹
   assoc_end_class end =  ⟹
   assoc_refer_class ends  role"

code_pred [show_modes] assoc_refer_class .

inductive class_roles where
  "assoc |∈| fmdom assocs ⟹
   fmlookup assocs assoc = Some ends ⟹
   assoc_refer_class ends  from ⟹
   role |∈| fmdom ends ⟹
   fmlookup ends role = Some end ⟹
   role ≠ from ⟹
   class_roles assocs  assoc from role"

code_pred [show_modes] class_roles .

values "{(x, y, z, a). class_roles associations x y z a}"
```

This predicate can be evaluated very fast (please see the last line above).

I need to prove that all association ends are unique for each class. For simplicity I'm trying to prove it for the `Employee` class:

```
lemma fmupd_to_rhs:
  "fmupd k x xm = y ⟷ y = fmupd k x xm"
  by auto

lemma class_roles_unique:
  "class_roles associations Employee assoc1 from role ⟹
   class_roles associations Employee assoc2 from role ⟹ assoc1 = assoc2"
  apply (erule class_roles.cases; erule class_roles.cases;
     erule assoc_refer_class.cases; erule assoc_refer_class.cases)
  unfolding fmupd_to_rhs
  apply (simp)
  apply (elim disjE)
  apply auto[1]
  apply auto[1]
  apply auto[1]
  (* And so on... Proving of each case is very slow *)
```

The problem is that it's very slow. Is it possible to simplify a `class_roles` predicate using lemmas generated by `code_pred`? Or could you suggest a better approach to prove this lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `code_pred` command generates equations for `class_roles`, one for each inferred mode, and `values` uses them. The theorem `class_roles.equation` shows them all. If you want to use them to prove your lemma, you must first transform goal or the lemma statement such that one of the generated `class_role_...` constants appears. Doing this manually is pretty cumbersome.

You get much better automation if you let the predicate compiler do this transformation for you. Since the lemma contains universally quantified variables (`assoc1`, `assoc2`, `from`, and `role`), I recommend that you define the negation of the lemma statement as an inductive predicate, as the negation turns the universal quantifier into an existential, which is modelled by a free variable in the assumptions. Then, you can use the proof method `eval` to do the heavy work:

```
inductive foo where
  "foo" if 
  "class_roles associations Employee assoc1 from role"
  "class_roles associations Employee assoc2 from role"
  "assoc1 ≠ assoc2"

code_pred foo .

lemma class_roles_unique:
  assumes "class_roles associations Employee assoc1 from role"
    and "class_roles associations Employee assoc2 from role"
  shows "assoc1 = assoc2"
proof -
  have "¬ foo" by eval
  with assms show ?thesis by(simp add: foo.simps)
qed
```

Note that `eval` uses code generation and evaluation in PolyML, so it computes the result rather than proves it. That is, evaluation is not checked by Isabelle's kernel. The related proof method `code_simp` goes through the kernel, but it does not work out of the box in this example because the code setup for `String.asciis_of_literals` is missing in Isabelle2018.

The following lemmas provide the missing code equations for literal strings, but `code_simp` is very slow with literal strings (`normalization` is a bit faster, but not checked by Isabelle's kernel either).

```
definition dup_bit :: "bool ⇒ integer ⇒ integer" where
 "dup_bit b i = i + i + (if b then 1 else 0)"

lemma dup_bit_code [code]:
  "dup_bit True 0 = 1"
  "dup_bit False 0 = 0"
  "dup_bit True (Code_Numeral.Pos n) = Code_Numeral.Pos (num.Bit1 n)"
  "dup_bit False (Code_Numeral.Pos n) = Code_Numeral.Pos (num.Bit0 n)"
  "dup_bit True (Code_Numeral.Neg n) = - Code_Numeral.sub (num.Bit0 n) Num.One"
  "dup_bit False (Code_Numeral.Neg n) = Code_Numeral.Neg (num.Bit0 n)"
  by(simp_all add: dup_bit_def Code_Numeral.sub_def nat_of_num_add num_eq_iff)
    (metis diff_numeral_special(1) numeral_Bit0 numeral_plus_numeral sub_num_simps(2))

fun integer_of_bits :: "bool list ⇒ integer" where
  "integer_of_bits [] = 0"
| "integer_of_bits (b # bs) = dup_bit b (integer_of_bits bs)"

lemma asciis_of_literal_code [code]: 
  "String.asciis_of_literal (STR '''') = []"
  "String.asciis_of_literal (String.Literal b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 s) =
     integer_of_bits [b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6] # String.asciis_of_literal s"
  including literal.lifting by(transfer; simp add: dup_bit_def; fail)+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However I don't understand why the code setup is missing. There is a `String.explode_code` lemma in the theory. What a lemma is required? Is it available in a development version?

Comment: The problem is that `String.asciis_of_literal` has no code theorems attached to it. There is a custom serialization configured for `String.asciis_of_literal` in the theory `String.literal`, but such serialization is only used for generating code like in `eval`, not for symbolic evaluation with `normalization` or `code_simp`. Thet thus cannot compare whether two `String.literal` values are the same. The development version http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/f2c3512df446/src/HOL/String.thy has the same problem. To find a solution, you'd first have to understand the current code setup.

Comment: I updated my answer with code equations that work for `String.asciis_of_literal`.